# Nautilus - When I select to open with gEdit, settings aren't saved

Tags: nautilus, scripts, gedit

A few days ago I decided to activate the option to run scripts in Nautilus by double clicking on it. But I also edit some a lot so whenever I want to edit them, I have to right click them, hover my mouse on the "Open With" menu and select an application there to edit the script with.

However, I'd like to edit them with GEdit. GEdit however, is not in the list of available applications to open with. So, to edit my scripts with GEdit, I click on "Another Application" and select GEdit.

But here is the thing. GEdit is not saved by default as an option in the submenu with the list of available applications to open the script with. It only shows LibreOffice, MonoDevelop and Notepad (Wine's version). But each time I want to edit a script, I have to click "Another Application" and select GEdit from there. Which isn't entirely practical if you know what I mean. So my question is, how can I "fix" this?

Thanks in advance!
TBJ

Answer (score 0):

In file `/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop` change as sudo

```
Exec=gedit %U
to
Exec=gedit %F

and
MimeType=text/plain;
to
MimeType=text;
```

The different MimeTypes are explained here : http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text

Hope it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. It still won't show up in that sub-menu.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the `defaults.list` file with `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` and look for the `[Default Applications]` entry. If it doesn't exist, add it.

Now add the following

```
text/*=gedit.desktop
```

Save the file and run `pkill nautilus`.

Comment: This didn't work for me because the file "defaults.list" did not exist in that folder. So I made that file myself but adding that data didn't make a difference.